# pattern matching and replace with regexp_replace

Tags: sql, oracle

Example

Input string        :      `OUT for GLE gle gle. single mingle ringle asdfgle  gleret GLE`

executing the below udpate statement

```
update TICKET
set desription_Modified = regexp_replace(desription_Modified, ' GLE | GLE|GLE ', ' XXXXX ',1,0,'i' )
where issue_key='ad';
```

Current replacement :      `OUT for XXXXX  XXXXX gle. sin XXXXX min XXXXX rin XXXXX asdf XXXXX  XXXXX ret XXXXX`

Expected output     :      `OUT for XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX. single mingle ringle asdfgle  gleret XXXXX`

issue : its replacing the `gle` from the normal words ( like :  `single mingle ringle`), i don't want the pattern to be replaced when its part of the word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the occurrences of 'gle' that are preceded and followed by a non-word character and/or the beginning or end of the string.

```
with
     inputs ( str ) as (
       select 'OUT for GLE gle gle. single mingle ringle asdfgle  gleret GLE' from dual
     )
select regexp_replace(str, '(\W|^)gle(\W|$)', '\1XXXXX\2', 1, 0, 'i') as new_str
from   inputs
;


NEW_STR
-------------------------------------------------------------------
OUT for XXXXX gle XXXXX. single mingle ringle asdfgle  gleret XXXXX
```

Take a close look at the output though: there is still a **gle** in it. This is because the space preceding it is ALSO the space following the first GLE in the string; that space is already used in the first match, so it can't be reused to find a second match.

The only solution I know of, to deal with this kind of situation, is to call the same function a second time, on the result of the first call.

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace str, ...., ....,   ), ...., ....)  ....
```